# Index all derived classes of base class ravendb

Tags: c#, ravendb

Our project has a framework and an own code base, which implements entities of the framework.

The idea is also to have several indexes in the framework that will return the results of all inheritances of certain framework types like user.

Apparantly, the only way Raven supports this (without creating the index on the highest level and manually adding maps) is to store all objects in the same collection by overwriting the Clr-type. However, this means we lose the derived information and cannot query on it.

Some samples:

```
class A { 
    public string Id {get; set; }, 
    public string Name {get; set; } 
}
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
class D : C { }
```

Then I want to query something along the lines of:

```
store.Query<IndexOfA>().Where(a => a.Name == "foo").As<A>().ToList();
```

AND be able to still do this;

```
store.Query<IndexOfC>().As<C>().ToList()
```

My idea was to add a convention that saves both the derived and the base class to the metadata when storing documents in RavenDB, but I have no idea how to go about this and cannot find any documentation on the subject.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index that used a multi map index with `AddMapForAll<Base>`, which will generate a separate entry for each derived class.
You could then use that index to do polymorphic queries.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is close to what we were looking for, but since we have multiple projects we had to create an extension that actually searched all assemblies for the derived classes. Perhaps an idea to add an overload method that supports this to the Raven source?

Comment: The answer is lacking a [link to an article](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/indexes/multi-map-indexes) in the official documentation explaining how it helps.